# Javascript shuffle letter

Tags: javascript, jquery

Shuffle letters from [tutorialzine](http://tutorialzine.com/2011/09/shuffle-letters-effect-jquery/)

**Note**: I am very novice. I just rearranged the codes logically based on the download.

When the page loads, I would like to have the text in `h2` blank or faded out and when the pause expires then begin to appear as it shuffles. Right now it is showing up right away then shuffles.

```
$(function(){
    var container = $("h1")
    container.shuffleLetters();

    var container = $("h2")
    setTimeout(function(){
    container.shuffleLetters();
    }, 4000);
});
```

Comment: So set the visibility to hidden and call fadeIn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
$(function(){
    var container = $("h1")
    container.shuffleLetters();

    var container = $("h2")
        container.hide();//OR  .fadeOut()

    setTimeout(function(){
    container.show();//OR .fadeIn()
    container.shuffleLetters();
    }, 4000);
});
```

Comment: Yes that worked. I appreciate it very much. I am laughing at the -1. Rough. But hey you were very helpful. I understand. Thanks again.